# Djangos builtin server trying to implement self hosted font

Tags: django, fonts, font-face, custom-font

I have a problem concerning Django and custom fonts.. Which way ever I try to use a custom font of this type

```
@font-face {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'abc';
    src: url('abc.eot');
    src: url('abc.woff');
    src: url('abc.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}
```

or this type

```
@font-face {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'abc';
    src: url('abc.eot');
    src: url('abc.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('abc.woff') format('woff'),
      url('abc.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('abc.svg#cde') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}
```

Django's builtin server ("python manage.py runserver") is printing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "c:\users\myName\documents\github\django-trunk\django\contrib\staticfiles\
handlers.py", line 65, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "c:\users\myName\documents\github\django-trunk\django\core\handlers\wsgi.p
y", line 191, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "c:\users\myName\documents\github\django-trunk\django\contrib\staticfiles\
handlers.py", line 55, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "c:\users\myName\documents\github\django-trunk\django\contrib\staticfiles\
handlers.py", line 48, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "c:\users\myName\documents\github\django-trunk\django\contrib\staticfiles\
views.py", line 41, in serve
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\myName\documents\github\django-trunk\django\views\static.py", li
ne 68, in serve
    response["Last-Modified"] = http_date(statobj.st_mtime)
  File "c:\users\myName\documents\github\django-trunk\django\utils\http.py", line
 119, in http_date
    return formatdate(epoch_seconds, usegmt=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\email\utils.py", line 175, in formatdate
    now = time.gmtime(timeval)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
"GET /this/is/the/correct/path/customfont.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

it does not matter if I link the customfont.css via `<link>`, copy&paste the content into my base.css (which is loaded correctly) or embed it into the .html file with `<script>@font-face..</script>`. I tried different fonts, too.

Excerpt from my settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'CEST'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

even though I am not using anything besides `DEBUG = True` by now.
My machine is running Windows 8 64bit if it matters.

Any ideas anyone? Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the "last modified" value on the file itself. Possibly the file was created on a computer with an offset clock, or some such.

Ref:

- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15120
- [Why am I getting 500 errors when serving web font files in my CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302547/why-am-i-getting-500-errors-when-serving-web-font-files-in-my-css)

Try updating the file with the following command:

```
copy /b customfont.ttf +,,
```

(That's a Windows equivalent of *nix "touch" command, ref: https://superuser.com/a/764721/66285 )

Comment: Updating the .css file and all the font files (abc.eot, abc.svg, abc.ttf, abc.woff) using this method is the fix! Thank you a lot.